# MongoDB query with multi-select filter with no selection scenario

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have filters in the front-end of a web application, and most of them are multi-select filters.

I am trying to write a mongo aggregate query that handles two kinds of scenarios.

1. A user selects values from a multi-select dropdown filter. The query will fetch those selected values and return relevant data back to the client.
2. A user doesn't select anything from the multi-select
   dropdown filter. In such cases, the query should return all the data.

The query should be something like below. Obviously, the below query is not working.

```
db.hospitals.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            hosp_name: {
                $cond: {
                    if: {
                        $in: [""]
                    }, then: "*", else: $in: ["ABC Hospital", "DEF Hospitals"] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                "IP/OP": "$ip_op"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Here, in the conditional block, I am trying to convey the below meaning:

1. If a user doesn't select any value in the hospital name multi-select dropdown filter, then display records of IP/OP for **all** the hospitals.
2. However, if a user selects the name of hospitals from the multi-select dropdown, then display records of IP/OP for the **selected** hospitals.

How to correctly construct this query?

---

EDIT:

I have tried `$or` condition as well. Though it is working, but it is showing empty result for no-selection scenario. The result doesn't suit my scenario. I know i am missing something.

```
db.hospital_baseline.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [{hospital_name: {$in: [""]}}, {hospital_name: {$in: ["ABC Hospital"]}}]
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                "Manufacturer Name": "$manufacturer_name"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: You can use `$expr` in the `$match` stage but the way you are using is obviously not correct - refer the MongoDB Manual.

Comment: I have tried the model as instructed in mongo manual. i am not getting intended results with that. Updated the query in the EDIT section.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to build your query programmatically in your code, first thing check the select array :

- if its empty , then your aggregation will be only $group stage , without any match condition
- if it's not empty , that means there is a selection , then you aggregation will be $match stage for the selected items and $group stage .

Comment: Can’t we do this at the query level?

Comment: maybe you can find a way to achieve that , but I believe it's better to keep the query simple as much as possible , better for index matching , and for later debugging .

Comment: Hi…do you an example or a template to achieve that in a query?